# UniqueDecodeError from urllib2 output from webpage with no non-unicode characters

Tags: json, python-2.7, urllib2

I am trying to read data off an api webpage using urllib2 in Python2.7. I am using the following lines to read the page:

```
url = 'https://api.edamam.com/api/nutrition-data?app_id=<my_app_id>&app_key=<my_app_key>&ingr=1cheeseburger'
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = json.load(json_obj)
```

These lines give me this error (the error is on the last line in the above code):

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I understand that this error means that there are non-unicode characters in `json_obj` but I am not sure why this is the case, because the same url opens in a browser and the first few lines on the webpage looks like the following:

```
{
"uri" : "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_2a58ff3e1fec41d79da72f0be446baaa
"calories" : 312,
"totalWeight" : 119.0,
"dietLabels" : [ "BALANCED" ],
"healthLabels" : [ "PEANUT_FREE", "TREE_NUT_FREE", "ALCOHOL_FREE" ],
"cautions" : [ ],
"totalNutrients" : {
"ENERC_KCAL" : {
  "label" : "Energy",
  "quantity" : 312.96999999999997,
  "unit" : "kcal"
},
```

As you can see, there are no non-unicode characters on this webpage, so I don't really follow what is going on.

Comment: It's hard to help you, without being able to make a request on the same api, however, you can show us the plain text you received from the json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)` .

Comment: So I am still not sure what the cause of the error was, but I fixed it using Requests:     
`r = requests.get(url)`
 `data = r.json()`